# An exercise on calculus

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\mathbb{R}_+$ denote the set of positive real numbers
>
> (a) Show that the continous function $f: \mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f = 1/(x+1)$ is bounded but doesn't achieve a max or min
>
> (b) Repeat (a), but let $f = \sin(1/x)$ and show that it is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}_+$

(a) I have two methods, I already know the second method is wrong, but would like a harsh criticism why.

(i) Okay first of all, since $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}_+$, that is for some $a \in \mathbb{R}_+$, we can verify that it is continuous at $a$. So it is trivially bounded. I probably shouldn't just state this because it doesn't seem like the problem wants this kind of solution (my gut feeling, but would like an expert to tell me why I can't do this). So instead I show its sup and inf

Let $A = \{ x \in\mathbb{R}_+:  f = 1/(x+1)\}$, then $\sup_{x}_{x \in\mathbb{R}_+} A = 1$ and $\inf_{x}_{x \in\mathbb{R}_+} A = 0$. So it is bounded, but since neither $0$ nor $\infty$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}_+$, max and min doesn't exist. I know infinity is not a quantity, but you can follow my logic. Would be great if someone could clean it up

(ii) Okay the second method was induction. I tried using the same technique for sequences on functions. I assume there is some positive $M$ such that

$f(x) \leq M$, then I show $f(x + 1) \leq M$. Now the algebra works out great, and my inductive step was easily done using $1/(x + 1 + 1) < 1/(x + 1) < M$. But obviously something was missing.

(b) Same idea, $x \to 0^+$, $f \to +\infty$, so $\sup_{x \in\mathbb{R}_+}= DNE$ and $\inf_{x}_{x \in\mathbb{R}_+}  = 0$ as $x \to \infty$

Since neither 0 or infinity belong to the domain, it can't have a max or min. However since it has a sup and inf, it is bounded. Is stating $\mathbb{R}_+$ not compact which implies non-uniform continuity good enough?

Note that this was a problem in Munkres in which neither the Mean Value Theorem or Derivatives were introduced yet, so I can't take derivatives and set it to $0$ (you get the drill)

Comment: I don't understand what your set $A$ is. Did you mean $A = \{ f(x): x\in \mathbb{R}_+\}$?

Comment: Continuous implies bounded? I don't think so --- is $f(x)=x$ bounded?

Comment: Also, you need a base case for induction. If you're trying to do induction on the reals, the base case is all $x$ with $0\lt x\le1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I meant to say continuous at a point and within a neighbourhood of $a$, $f$ is bounded. Probably irrelevant point. I'll fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Okay first of all, since $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R_+$, that is for some $a\in\Bbb R_+$, we can verify that it is continuous at $a$. So it is trivially bounded.

This makes no sense, I’m afraid. Consider the function $g(x)=x$ on $\Bbb R$; it’s continuous, but it’s certainly not bounded on $\Bbb R$. Continuity of $f$ at $a$ shows that there is some interval around $a$ on which $f$ is bounded, but it says nothing about what happens elsewhere.

In order to show that $f(x)=\frac1{x+1}$ is bounded on $\Bbb R_+$ you must show that there are real numbers $m$ and $M$ such that $m\le f(x)\le M$ for all $x\in\Bbb R_+$. You actually did this in the next paragraph, when you pointed out that $\sup_{x\in\Bbb R_+}f(x)=1$ and $\inf_{x\in\Bbb R_+}f(x)=0$.

Induction (in the form in which you’re familiar with it) is a way to prove statements about **integers**. Specifically, if $P(n)$ is some assertion about the integer $n$, induction says that if you can prove $P(n_0)$ for some integer $n_0$, and you can prove that $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$ whenever $n\ge n_0$, then $P(n)$ is true for all **integers** $n\ge n_0$. In this problem you need to prove that something is true for all **real numbers** greater than $0$, which is another kettle of fish altogether.

---

In (b) you’re not paying attention: the function is $f(x)=\sin\frac1x$, not $f(x)=\frac1x$. This is certainly bounded, since $-1\le\sin u\le 1$ for all $u\in\Bbb R$. Look at the graph of $y=\sin\frac1x$: it oscillates between $-1$ and $1$, and it does so faster and faster as $x\to 0^+$. Suppose that $n$ is a large positive integer, and $x_n=\frac1{n\pi}$. Then $f(x_n)=\sin\pi n=0$, but if $n$ is large, the graph is very steep at that point. Suppose that you want to find a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)|<\frac12$ whenever $|x-x_n|<\delta$; show that $\delta$ will have to be smaller than $\frac1{n\pi}-\frac1{(n+1)\pi}$. Then use this to show that no matter how small you take $\delta>0$, you can find integers $n$ so large that $\delta$ doesn’t work at $x_n$: there is an $x$ such that $|x-x_n|<\delta$, but $|f(x)|\ge\frac12$. This will show that $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: @sizz: (1) A spoiler for what? (2) Using $P(x+h)$ doesn’t help: you’re still dealing only with a discrete set of points, $x,x+h,x+2h,\dots$. Induction simply isn’t an appropriate tool here.

Comment: A spoiler over (b). Since I completely computed sup and inf for the wrong function

Comment: @sizz: What I wrote starting with ‘Suppose that $n$ is a large positive integer’ is a fairly big hint for (b).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott $m\le g(x)\le M$, I think you mean $f$ instead of $g$.

Comment: @GitGud: I certainly do; thanks for catching it.

Comment: Perhaps, we may also note that every continuous function from a compact space into $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded (In order not to completely discourage the continuous->bounded implication.).

Comment: @sizz: You shouldn’t be trying to work with an object $\infty$ in the first place: there is no such real number. All you have to say is that for all $x>0$, $x+1>0$, and therefore $\frac1{x+1}>0$. On the other hand, you can get $\frac1{x+1}$ arbitrarily close to $0$ by taking $x$ large enough. (E.g., to get $\frac1{x+1}<\frac1n$, just take $x=n$.) It follows immediately that $\inf_{x>0}\frac1{x+1}=0$.

Comment: @sizz: Let $A=\operatorname{ran}f$. Suppose that $A$ has a minimum element; call it $u$. We know that $a>0$ for each $a\in A$, so $0\notin A$, and therefore $u\ne 0$, and clearly $u$ isn’t a negative number. We also know that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $a\in A$ such that $a<\epsilon$, so $u$ cannot be any positive number. Since $u$ is neither positive, negative, nor $0$, $u$ does not exist. Of course since $A$ is bounded below, $\inf A$ does exist; indeed, what I’ve written is enough to prove that $\inf A=0$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, can I do this? Let $\epsilon = 1$, then choose a sequence of $x_n = 1/n\pi$ and show that $|x_{n+1} - x_{n}| = |1/(\pi k(k+1) ) \to 0 $, but $|f(x_{k+1}) - f(x_k)| = |\sin(k \pi) - \sin(k \pi + \pi)| = |0 + 0| \geq 1$, a contradiction

Comment: @sizz: $|0+0|\ge 1$? Are you sure? :-) You could do something similar, though, if you took $x_n=\frac2{n\pi}$ instead, so that $|f(x_n)|$ is alternately $1$ and $0$.

Comment: @sizz: $\sin k\pi$ and $\sin(k+1)\pi$? Yes, they do. But $0$ is not greater than or equal to $1$.

Comment: @sizz: It doesn’t contradict anything. What do you think that it contradicts?

Comment: Assume on the contrary that it does converge. Let $\epsilon = 1$. Choosen $x_n = 1/(2\pi n + \pi/2)$ and $y_n = 1/(2\pi n - \pi/2)$. So $|x - y| \to 0$, yet $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)| = 2 < 1$, a contradiction

Comment: @sizz: That’s basically correct. However, you mean that $|x_n-y_n|\to 0$ and that $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|=2>\epsilon$ for all $n$; that’s the contradiction.

Comment: @sizz: Not quite. You need the subscripts in $|x_n-y_n|\to 0$, your last inequality goes the wrong way, and it’s important that that inequality holds for all $n$. (Actually, it need only hold for infinitely many $n$, but this is crucial and has to be said; and since it does hold for all $n$, it’s simpler just to say that.)

Comment: What if I say replace it with $\nless$? Can I ask what your answer (in your initial suggestion) was implying then?

Comment: @sizz: Sure, $\nless$ is fine. In my original answer I suggested that you prove directly that $f$ is not uniformly continuous by showing that there is no $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\frac12$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$.

Comment: Sorry I should be more specific, what $x$ and $y$ values were you thinking of?

Comment: Would it also be possible to have chosen (for my example) just one $x$ and $y$ value? Say I choose $x = \pi/2$ and $y = 3\pi/2$ and the algebra still would have worked. Of course this choice wouldn't be as general

Comment: @sizz: I gave the $x$ values: they’re my $x_n$’s. For the $x$ such that $|x-x_n|<\delta$ but $|f(x)-f(x_n)|>\frac12$ the most obvious choices are $$\frac1{\left(n\pm\frac12\right)\pi}\;.$$ No, one value can’t possibly tell you anything. Think about what uniform continuity means: it’s not a statement about what happens at one or two points.